# Determine the number of elements that belongs to a user-defined range of values

Tags: c

Need to solve a problem in C. It is required to create a two-dimensional array (3x3) whcih will be filled with random values in range (-16, 27). And then i should write a function which determines the number of elements that belongs to a user-defined range of values.
Tried to do on my own, but couldn't. Help, please!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
// function to count elements within given range
int countInRange(int arr[9], int n, int x, int y)
{
    // initialize result
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
 
        // check if element is in range
        if (arr[i] >= x && arr[i] <= y)
            count++;
    }
    return count;
}
 
// driver function
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int arr[9];
    int i;
    
    int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        arr[i] = rand() % 25 + 16;
    }
    return 0;
    countInRange(arr, 9, 5, 25);
}
```

Comment: I'd start with a 2D array that's 3x3.

Comment: The `return` in main() doesn't make sense. Didn't the compiler warn you about unreachable code?

Comment: The random calc is incorrect. The range is `27 - -16` so it should be `-16 + rand() % 44`

Comment: No, actually. The problem is that I don't know how take a range from a user and then compare it to my array.

Comment: What is your specific question? What do you expect, what happens instead?

Comment: Aside: you have `int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);` but ignore that when you pass `9` to the function.

Comment: I just put random values to check if there no errors in code. But even with these values code does not output anything

Comment: Use `fgets` to read user input and `strtol` to get the number

Comment: `countInRange(arr, 9, 5, 25);` --> `int cnt = countInRange(arr, 9, 5, 25); printf("Result: %d\n", cnt);`

Comment: So, what should I add to make this code work and satisfy the condition of the task?

Comment: `return 0;` **before** the function call !!! ups... delete it

Comment: It worked, thank you! And one thing more, how to add fgets correctly to code so I can take user input?

Comment: @WeatherVane I don't think the call should be `countInRange(arr, 9, -16, 27)` as that would be the whole range. I think OP wants `countInRange(arr, 9, x, y)` where `x` and `y` are user input

Comment: @4386427 ah yes, but `countInRange(arr, size, x, y)`

Comment: Did you search the net for "c read a number using fgets" ? I did and the very first is a link to an SO question that answers exactly that...

Comment: Did not get how I can implement that code to my

Comment: "It worked, thank you!" What worked? Fixing the return bug? If that was the only problem then we can close this question as "simple typo".

Answer (score 1):

1. Create the 2D array instead of 1D array
2. Use the correct type for sizes (`size_t`)
3. Calling the function after the return makes no sense at all.

```
size_t getNumber(size_t rows, size_t cols, int (*array)[cols], int min, int max)
{
    size_t num = 0;
    if(rows && cols && array)
    {
        for(size_t r = 0; r < rows; r++)
            for(size_t c = 0; c < cols; c++)
                if(array[r][c] >= min && array[r][c] <= max) num++;
    }
    return num;
}

// driver function
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int arr[3][3];
    size_t i;
    
    size_t size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0][0]);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        arr[i/3][i%3] = rand() % 25 + 16;
        printf("[%d]%c", arr[i/3][i%3], (i+1) % 3 ? ' ' : '\n');
    }
    printf("Number of elements in range : %zu\n", getNumber(3, 3, arr, 5, 25));
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Mc5YfME7r